# Is there any limit on how complex DynamoDB condition expressions can be?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a limit on how many subexpressions joined by `AND` can be included in a single DynamodDB [condition expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)?

I couldn't find a documented limit in the AWS list of DDB service quotas (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

> Lengths
> The maximum length of any expression string is 4 KB. For
> example, the size of the ConditionExpression a=b is 3 bytes.
>
> The maximum length of any single expression attribute name or
> expression attribute value is 255 bytes. For example, #name is 5
> bytes; :val is 4 bytes.
>
> The maximum length of all substitution variables in an expression is 2
> MB. This is the sum of the lengths of all ExpressionAttributeNames and
> ExpressionAttributeValues.

From the same place you [linked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-expression-parameters)